# Parallel Period filter (MDX)

Tags: mdx

I want to add working days inside the `parallelperiod` function below, is there any way with filter or except (Like only working days, count until yesterday)?.
The code below for your info gets the measure X for the previous year `YTD`

```
 SUM(
   YTD(
   ParallelPeriod(
   [Χρονική Περίοδος].[Year Quarter Month].[Year Name],
   1,
   [Χρονική Περίοδος].[Year Quarter Month].[Year Name].&[Calendar 2015])
   ),
   [Measures].[X]
   )
```

Comment: do you have any attributes for working days inside your cube? e.g. an attribute hierarchy for weekday (Mon-Sun)? Is this the Date dimension: `[Χρονική Περίοδος]`?

Comment: Yes I have but parallelperiod tracks how many “members” are on each “level” in a user hierarchy. For example, it does not keep track of which months have 31 days and which months have 30 or 28 days. I have added the working days attribute at WHERE, I believe it does't work. Moreover when I ask for the previous YTD I meant 01/01/14-22/09/14, I think that I take results for all 2014 period.

Comment: please add the full script you are using

Comment: Best to handle it at source by adding calculated column in the date table. If not possible, you would need to handle this in MDX by creating calculated members. Obviously we would need to see how your date dimension looks like.